# Any purely functional language bindings available for Selenium2/WebDriver?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

While looking for any purely functional language bindings for Selenium2/WebDriver, I came across a repository for Haskell bindings for Selenium RC but not for the Selenium2/WebDriver.

I am interested in getting more comfortable with ideas of functional languages while sticking to Selenium2, if possible. I have been playing with Haskell for a month or so and understand that Haskell is a pure functional language so was wondering if they have any bindings for Selenium2. Otherwise, could you suggest any other functionally-oriented language bindings for Selenium2?

Comment: See also: [the selenium package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/selenium/0.2.3/doc/html/Test-Selenium-Server.html) (Selenium 1, not 2). It looks like all those bindings really do is translate a Selenium command into a String, and send it to a Selenium server.

Comment: Thanks for reconfirming the Selenium1 bindings bit. Will have a further look at the workings of these bindings.

Answer (score 10):

The reply is a bit late, but I've released a Haskell client for WebDriver on Hackage that you may be interested in: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver

Comment: Upvote! An excellent library but it could use an update: https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver/issues/60

Answer (score 5):

Though the project supports .NET, Java, Ruby, and Python out of the box, the Selenium WebDriver team has made it very easy to produce bindings for almost any language you care to. Most drivers now use a JSON-over-HTTP wire protocol, the commands of which are documented in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). As long as whatever language you are using has an HTTP client library and a JSON parsing library, you can create your own bindings with relative ease. A JVM-based language is far from necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason why purely functional language bindings are missing is that `Selenium`/`WebDriver` is mostly used by QA/Testers and it would be difficult for them to program in a `Haskell` or other functional language.

But you want to program with `WebDriver` in functional style you can use some JVM based language such as `Scala` or `clojure`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at those languages.

Comment: I don't see why ML, Haskell, OCaML, or any other functional language "would be difficult for [QA/Testers] to program in." Haskell, in particular, has had a library, QuickCheck, for automatically generating test cases for your programs. To top it off, QuickCheck is itself written in Haskell. I would find it more plausible that WebDriver is missing functional language bindings, simply because such languages aren't as popular as the C-style (C, C++, Java, PHP, C#) ones.